# VS Code Vs Visual Studio 2019 for azure function

Tags: visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I am learning Azure function and not able to decide,  should i use VS code Or VS2019 for the same.

This is what i found:

> VS Code:
>
> - Lightweight,
> - AZ function and c# extension available
> - Better integration with git

> Visual Studio:
>
> - Option to create azure function project directly from file > new project
> - Can use it to create other project types for example: web, console etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create Azure Function in 3 ways

- VSCode
- Visual Studio
- Azure portal

It depends on your scenario and integrations you need, both VS and VSCode has the features
needed, if you use VS it becomes more easier to create, manage and deploy since you dont have to install plugins separately, Go with VS by default. If you dont have VS you can achieve all these with VSCode by making plugins available.

Comment: yeah i am now using VS to create functions.. i find it much easier and more manageable.